# Xamarin.Forms & MvvmCross : Navigation and commands not work

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've created 4 projects:

- `MobileApp.Core`, which contains my business code (.NET Standard 2.0 library)
- `MobileApp.Droid` (for Android 9)
- `MobileApp.iOS` (for iOS 11)
- `MobileApp.UI`, which contains Xamarin.Forms project (XAML)

...with some NuGet packages: `Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.X`, `MvvmCross.Forms 6.4.2`, `Xamarin.Essentials 1.4.0`, `Xamarin.Android.Support.XXX 28.X.X`, ...

- `HomePage` and `SecondPage` inherit from `MvxContentPage<TViewModel>` (in C# class and in XAML file).
- `HomeViewModel` and `SecondVieWModel` inherit from `BaseViewModel`, which inherits from `MvxViewModel`.

I've some services in my `BaseViewModel` injected into the constructor : `IMvxNavigationService`, `MyApp.Core.Services.IMyCustomService`. They works: `IMyCustomService` is registered in `MyApp.Core.App.Initialize()` method.

In my `HomeViewModel`, I've a `MyText` property (binded to an `Entry`: `<Entry Text="{Binding MyText}"/>`) and a command (binded to a `ToolbarItem`: `<ToolbarItem Text="Ok" Command="{Binding OkCommand}"/>`):

```
private string _myText;
public string MyText
{
    get => _myText;
    set => SetProperty(ref _myText, value);
}

public IMvxCommand OkCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(ExecuteOkCommandAsync, CanExecuteOkCommand);
private async Task ExecuteOkCommandAsync()
{
    await MyCustomService.SomeAsyncWork(); // it works
    await NavigationService.Navigate<MissionsViewModel>();
}
private bool CanExecuteOkCommand() => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyText);
```

## 2 unexpected behaviors

### Command remains unavailable

When I type something in my Entry, binded to `MyText` property, the command remains unavailable. I don't know why. `_myText` is really setted.

I've tried to use `SetProperty(ref T storage, T value, Action afterAction, string propertyName)` and call `OkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` when I notify that my property was changed:

```
public string MyText
{
    get => _myText;
    set => SetProperty(ref _myText, value, () => OkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(), nameof(MyText));
}
```

My command remains unavailable. For moment, it's stand by, i've replace `CanExecuteOkCommand` by `() => true`.

### Can't navigate from `HomeViewModel.Initialize()` method (✔ solved)

*Now, I want to navigate from HomeViewModel to SecondViewModel if something is true (file exists). I don't need parameters.*

*In `ExecuteOkCommandAsync` method, I call `await NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(SecondViewModel));`. When I navigate from here (command called), it's okay.*

*But when I try to navigate from `HomeViewModel.Initialize()` method, I've the view of `HomeViewModel` with a *back* button in the toolbar:*

```
public override async Task Initialize()
{
    IsBusy = true;

    if (true) // a real condition : if file exists, today is monday, ...
    {
        var result = await NavigationService.Navigate<SecondViewModel>();
    }

    var items = await MyCustomService.GetItemsAsync();
    Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(items);

    IsBusy = false;
}
```

*When I debug step by step:*

1. *`HomeViewModel.Initialize()` is called. `var result = await NavigationService.Navigate<SecondViewModel>();` too.*
2. *`SecondViewModel.Initialize()` is called.*
3. *the previous `result` variable (in `HomeViewModel.Initialize()`) is `true`.*
4. *The application shows `HomePage` (not `SecondPage` as expected).*

[image]

*When I tap on "OK" button, in the toolbar, I can navigate to the real `SecondPage` (and his `SecondViewModel`, obviously).*

*When I press on back button, from `HomePage`, I navigate to `SecondPage`...*

Comment: The only way I found to navigate from `HomePage` to `SecondPage` if a condition is true before any possible interaction, is to override the `ViewAppeared` method.

Answer (score 0):

I can override `ViewAppeared` method instead of `Initialize` task:

```
public class HomeViewModel 
{
    /* Ommited code  */
    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        var items = await MyCustomService.GetItemsAsync();
        // ...
    }

    public override void ViewAppeared()
    {
        base.ViewAppeared();
        if (true)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate<MissionsViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```